# Why can't I acces the public variable from the Test class in the main function?

Tags: java

I am new at learning Java and I do not understand why I can't println the variable `prvvar`. Why does it need to be set to static?

```
package myproject;

class Test
{
    private int prvvar=2;   
    public  int pbvar=3;    
}
```

Main class:

```
public class bycicleDemo
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test da = new Test();       
        System.out.println(Test.pbvar);
    }
}
```

Comment: because you are trying to access it through the class, not through it's instance. try: 
System.out.println(da.pbvar);

Answer (score 1):

In Java non static variables are Object associated and static variables Class associated.

In your case `pbvar` is non static variable, so you can't access it using class name you need to access it using object. As below

```
public class BycicleDemo
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test da = new Test();       
        System.out.println(da.pbvar);
    }
}
```

If this `pbvar` would have been declared as static as below then calling with class name was correct.

```
package myproject;

class Test
{
    public static int pbvar=3; 
    private int prvvar=2;      
}
```

And class name should start with Capital letter **BycicleDemo** as per Java standards.

Answer (score 0):

Since `pbvar` is not static you cant access it through the class. Access it through your newly created instance instead `System.out.println(da.pbvar);`.

If you declare `pbvar` like this `public static int pbvar=3;` your example: `System.out.println(Test.pbvar);` would work.